# How to discover what events are launched when I interact with a control?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose that i have a button:

```
<button id="mybutton"></button>
```

Then in some javascript could exists an event handler:

```
$("#mybutton").click(funtion() {
////
});
```

In another javascript there are another event handler:

```
$(document).on("click", "#mybutton", null, function() {
});
```

And a lot more...

How can I discover at real time which event handlers are launched when I clicked the button?
Something like put a breakpoint in every event handler of #mybutton without knowing where are located the event handler or AOP in javascript.

Comment: If you use Chrome, get this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi?hl=en

Comment: JavaScript can't pause the execution of other functions. You will need a browser which provides this as a devtool.

Comment: Most browsers have a 'pause javascript' option (in Chrome it's F12/Sources/F8).  This will stop on the next bit of js code.  Set this, then click your button.  Of course, this only works if the page isn't overly complicated (eg no setIntervals or 100s of mouse-over effects).  So only of limited use (hence comment, not answer)